# I am unable to retrieve localStorage data, as stored format appears different?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, local-storage

I am a newbie to programming, and apologies in advance if this has been answered before.  I have done some searches and it doesn't look to me like this specific question has been answered.

Before attempting to store a large volume of data in localStorage (HTML5, Chrome, Windows), I have tried some sample data and attempted to store data.  When I do a console display before storing the variable shows all the data correctly.   I also seem to have some success because I see the sample data in the localStorage via the console.

However, I am baffled that the data appears multiple times in a continuous line.  When I try to retrieve the data with a getItem, I get a null.  I am not doing anything fancy for either storing or for retrieving data.

The code I use for storing and retrieving are shown below, as also the data in the localStorage as viewed by the Chrome console.

I have also tried JSONstringify in one of my attempts.

Storing:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('result', zlldata);
```

Retrieving:

```
GETzlldata = window.localStorage.getItem(zlldata);
zlldata = JSON.parse(GETzlldata);
```

Data in the LS look like this:  (I tried 2 different approaches, once with 'this.zlldata' and the other time with 'result' in the setItem attempts.

```
this.zlldata: "undefined"
{"zipLatLong": [
    {"zipcode":"35004","lat":"33.606379","longit":"-86.50249"},
    {"zipcode":"35005","lat":"33.592585","longit":"-86.95969"},
    {"zipcode":"35006","lat":"33.451714","longit":"-87.23957"},
    {"zipcode":"35007","lat":"33.232422","longit":"-86.80871"}
    ]
}
{"zipLatLong": [
    {"zipcode":"35004","lat":"33.606379","longit":"-86.50249"},
    {"zipcode":"35005","lat":"33.592585","longit":"-86.95969"},
    {"zipcode":"35006","lat":"33.451714","longit":"-87.23957"},
    {"zipcode":"35007","lat":"33.232422","longit":"-86.80871"}
    ]
}
```

Question I have is how do I retrieve the data. I mentioned that data looks different because of all the 'return' characters that show up.  Regardless the data should be 'retrievable'.  I have allocated enough space in localStorage for the purpose at 5 MB.  The format is the same for all records.  The purpose of this exercise is a project that I am doing for the course and this approach has other uses.  I am aware that in the real world other easier ways are available (e.g. via APIs to websites).

Appreciate any help.   Just as additional info, I don;t need to retrieve all data each time, but only need to validate that the zipcode (for eg, exists)

Thanks again in advance and sorry for the lengthy post

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: @crowder -  thanks, yes i concede, and apologies

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

To put complex data into `localStorage`:

```
localStrorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify(theData));
```

To read complex data out of `localStorage`:

```
var theData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("name") || "null");
if (theData) {
    // It wasn't there, initialize it
}
```

(Naturally, the above only works with values that can be converted to and from JSON. If you have values that don't convert readily, like dates, you can use a *replacer function* with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and a *reviver function* with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to handle them.)

Full example on jsFiddle (Stack Snippets don't allow `localStorage`): https://jsfiddle.net/aj2mq4rz/1

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="field-name">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Age:
    <input type="text" id="field-age">
  </label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn-save" value="Save">
```

JavaScript:

```
// On page load, read our data
var theData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("someName") || "null");
if (!theData) {
    theData = {
      name: "",
      age: 0
  };
}
var nameField = document.getElementById("field-name");
nameField.value = theData.name;
var ageField = document.getElementById("field-age");
ageField.value = theData.age;
document.getElementById("btn-save").onclick = function() {
  // Update our object
    theData.name = nameField.value;
  theData.age = +ageField.value;

  // And save it to local storage
  localStorage.setItem("someName", JSON.stringify(theData));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!   That helps.

Comment: @Venugopal -  Thanks! I appreciate it.

Comment: @Crowder -  Sincerest thanks for the code above. Immensely helpful.   I am working on this and will let you know how this went, a bit later today.  Wanted to acknowledge for now.   Regards

Comment: @T,J,Crowder   Your coding suggestion worked well.   Thanks very much.  I had had problems retrieving the data.   Your code structure helped me sort it out.    Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are using:
`window.localStorage.setItem('result', zlldata);` for storing but using `window.localStorage.getItem(zlldata);`for retrieving. You cannot retrieve with the value, you need to use the key. So, you need to use `getItem('result');`

Comment: I had compounded errors, as I had coded the variables incorrectly in my js. With T.J. Crowder's script I covered some good distance and  I was then able to access the file from local storage with the key as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool that will do this for you, that is, allow you to transparently set and get a javascript object (and other primitives) as a localStorage key value. (It does the conversion so you don't have to.) It's called [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage.js).

To use it, first instantiate your storage object:

```
localData = localDataStorage( 'my.project' );
```

Then, store a key value (in this case, your object unchanged):

```
localData.set( 'key1', '{"zipLatLong": [{"zipcode":"35004","lat":"33.606379","longit":"-86.50249"},{"zipcode":"35005","lat":"33.592585","longit":"-86.95969"},{"zipcode":"35006","lat":"33.451714","longit":"-87.23957"},{"zipcode":"35007","lat":"33.232422","longit":"-86.80871"}]}' );
```

Then, read it back:

```
x = localData.get( 'key1' );

--> "{"zipLatLong": [{"zipcode":"35004","lat":"33.606379","longit":"-86.50249"},{"zipcode":"35005","lat":"33.592585","longit":"-86.95969"},{"zipcode":"35006","lat":"33.451714","longit":"-87.23957"},{"zipcode":"35007","lat":"33.232422","longit":"-86.80871"}]}"
```